# How can gravity be describe as a carried on gravitons if light is affected by gravity but no effect on gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, mass-energy, quantum-gravity

if photons are emitting graviton while it going near to mass then this graviton should effect the mass the much as the graviton that object with mass emit, and we know light have no mass  so it not have an effect  on gravity. another problem I was thinking about  is that gravity may expends in the speed of light but when object is going through curve of space time and getting way for mass we may say that the gravity force it fill is weaker but if it just follow the space-time curve then it would be effected immediately, and if it result of emitting graviton then the effect would be delayed till the graviton get to the mass which would make the gravity getting weaker in the upside relation as we except because it would be more delayed the much you get a way from gravity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classical general relativity  any object with a four vector , i.e. has energy and momentum, contributes  to the curvature of space time that is gravity. Light has energy and momentum in classical electromagnetism so the classical gravitational fields are affected.

In quantum mechanics classical light emerges from photons, and photons have a four vector. In effective quantization of gravity, which is the frame where gravitons are expected as the gauge bosons of gravity, any interaction between photons and a gravitationa field happens withvirtual gravitons, so the argument of masses does not hold. There are integrals with bounds over which the integration for the probable interaction of photons with the gravitational field of massive objects is represented by **virtual gravitons**. Real on mass shell gravitons have not been seen, the way photons are seen, so it has no meaning to talk about graviton photon scattering.

You have to study quantum field theory to be able to really understand this.

When gravity is definitively quantized one expects that the same will hold true.

Comment: but we can assume that light doesn't effect on mass because otherwise we may say that light coming from far a way would accumulate  because the photon would attract each other for very long and photon can be at the same place because they don't have charge so it would create super massive point in space

Comment: two photons if there is an angle between them have a mass, that is spcecial relativity. Better go on with physics studies if you are really intersted to understand  what the current physics models do.

Comment: This is a really nice answer.